# Reverse for 'export2' with no arguments not found

Tags: javascript, python, django, templates

I have code identical to this but, obviously is a different view is being called. That code works but, for some reason I keep getting this error. Im new to django 2.1 so sorry if this is a simple fix.

**views.py**

```
def export_view(request,builddata=None):
  print(builddata)
  buildings = BuildingSearch.getBuildingString()
  return render(request, 'dashboard/export.html',{'buildlist': buildings,'builddata':builddata})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('export/<slug:builddata>/', views.export_view, name='export2'),
   path('export/', views.export_view, name='export'),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**export.html**

```
var times = ($("span#stringtime").text()).replace(" ","");
window.location.href = "{% url 'export2' %}/" + times + "/";
```

I'm getting this error when Im trying to access localhost:8000/export/ (the 'export' url)

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using `{% url 'export2' %}` in your template. But in your urlpatterns, The url for `export2` has a configuration as:

```
path('export/<slug:builddata>/', views.export_view, name='export2'),
```

This pattern is expecting a `slug`. So pass some content while calling the url as:

```
{% url 'export2' <something> %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the url `export2` is expecting `builddata` So, you have to pass the value of `builddata` in `{% url %}` for getting the reverse match.

```
window.location.href = "{% url 'export2' builddata='sample' %}";
```

From the code that you shared, I can see that you want to pass the `times` value in `builddata`. And `times` is a js variable.

So you can use this to inject js variable in `{% url %}`.

```
var destinationUrl = "{% url 'export2' builddata=123321 %}".replace((/123321/, times.toString());
window.location.href = destinationUrl;

// END
```

Comment: Fixed the issue! Thank you!!

Comment: Youre welcome @Madison . Mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.